# get quote's product attribute

Tags: php, magento, attributes, cart

Hi I'm trying to get a product attribute admin value or id (since it's multilanguage) from the cart items. I've tried many versions of code like this one:

```
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getId());
        $attribute = $_product->getAttribute('producttype');
    }
```

But I only ever get false or null. Also how can I be sure to not get the store specific language value, but the attributes admin value/id? Maybe there's an even better way to read out the item attributes directly from the quote items without having to load the product first? Thanks in advance!

---

Solved with:

```
    $session = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    foreach ($session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item)
    {
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
        $attributeId = $_product->getProducttype();
    }
```

and comparing by value ID instead of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the product's value for a specific shop, while the items in the quote belong to a different store view, you can do the folowing:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->setStoreId($adminStoreId)
    ->load($item->getId());

$value = $_product->getData('producttype');
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, I finally managed to get the producttype attribute outputted at all, so maybe I'll use your solution for the language specific next - thanks!